# jQuery toggle on all elements of the loop [Error]

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I'm with this product loop, each one has a Details box, which appears when you click "More +", but inside the loop it is showing the box of all products when I click on any one, like can i make this unique for each product?

UPDATE!

**Box I want to appear:**

```
        <div class="keyFeaturesBox">
            <div class="keyFeaturesBox-header">
                <i id="keyFeaturesClose" class="far fa-times-circle"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="keyFeaturesBox-container">
                <div class="features">
                    <i class="fas fa-car"></i>
                    <span>Front Wheel Drive</span>  
                </div>       
                <div class="features">
                    <i class="fas fa-car"></i>
                    <span>Front Wheel Drive</span>  
                </div>   
                <div class="features">
                    <i class="fas fa-car"></i>
                    <span>Front Wheel Drive</span>  
                </div>           
            </div>                
        </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div.keyFeaturesBox, div.viewSavingsBox {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 180px; max-height: 180px;  
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid rgba(112, 112, 112, .34);
}
```

**Loop:**

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($vehicles); $i++) { 
           echo '<div class="keyFeaturesBox">
                <div class="keyFeaturesBox-header">
                    <i id="keyFeaturesClose" class="far fa-times-circle"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="keyFeaturesBox-container">
                    <div class="features">
                        <i class="fas fa-car"></i>
                        <span>Front Wheel Drive</span>  
                    </div>       
                    <div class="features">
                        <i class="fas fa-car"></i>
                        <span>Front Wheel Drive</span>  
                    </div>   
                    <div class="features">
                        <i class="fas fa-car"></i>
                        <span>Front Wheel Drive</span>  
                    </div>           
                </div>                
            </div>';
}
```

**HTML Code:**

```html
<div class="vehicleDetails"><!-- Details start -->                
  <div class="keyFeatures">
    <span id="keyFeatures" class="keyFeatures-span">Key Features +</span>
  </div>
  <div class="viewSavings">
    <span id="viewSavings" class="viewSavings">View Savings +</span>
  </div>                
</div><!-- Details end -->
```

**jQuery code:**

```
// Features Box Toggle
$(".keyFeatures-span").click(function() { 
    $(".keyFeatures").toggleClass("selectedFeatures");
    $(".keyFeaturesBox").slideToggle("fast");;
});
```

Comment: where is the loop?

Comment: Sorry, update my question

Comment: Do you want to show keyFeaturesBox div when keyFeatures-span click? if so, how do you know which car clicked?

Comment: That's right, I have a Favorite button and it's unique for each product card, but with boxes it's not like that, if I click on Features + it shows the box of all products in the loop

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.closest()` to move up the DOM tree and match any selector.

The example below is fully commented.

You didn't provide any HTML for `.keyFeaturesBox` so that line might need adapting, as a guess you might need to use `.closest(".keyFeatures").find(".keyFeaturesBox")` to move up the DOM tree to the wrapper class and then search the children for the features box. This is difficult to work out without all the HTML.

---

Demo

```js
// Event trigger for click of .keyFeatures-span
$(".keyFeatures-span").click(function() {

  // Move up DOM tree and apply class selectedFeatures to first match
  $(this).closest(".keyFeatures").toggleClass("selectedFeatures");

  // You didn't include .keyFeaturesBox in your example HTML so you might need to adapt this
  $(this).closest(".keyFeaturesBox").slideToggle("fast");

});
```

```css
.selectedFeatures {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="vehicleDetails">
  <div class="keyFeatures">
    <span id="keyFeatures" class="keyFeatures-span">Key Features +</span>
  </div>
  <div class="viewSavings">
    <span id="viewSavings" class="viewSavings">View Savings +</span>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="vehicleDetails">
  <div class="keyFeatures">
    <span id="keyFeatures" class="keyFeatures-span">Key Features +</span>
  </div>
  <div class="viewSavings">
    <span id="viewSavings" class="viewSavings">View Savings +</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I updated my question, this solution changes the target class but does not show the box

Answer (score 0):

I have your code running like so:

```
<!-- Details start -->                
<div class="vehicleDetails">
    <div class="keyFeatures">
        <span id="keyFeatures" class="keyFeatures-span">Key Features +</span>
        <div class="keyFeaturesBox">
            <p>a feature</p>
            <p>a feature</p>
            <p>a feature</p>
            <p>a feature</p>
            <p>a feature</p>
            <p>a feature</p>
            <p>a feature</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="viewSavings">
        <span id="viewSavings" class="viewSavings">View Savings +</span>
    </div>                
</div>
<!-- Details end -->

<script>
    // Features Box Toggle
    $(".keyFeatures-span").click(function() { 
        let $parentNode = $(this).parent('.keyFeatures');
        $parentNode.toggleClass("selectedFeatures");
        $parentNode.find(">.keyFeaturesBox").slideToggle("fast");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I updated my question, this solution changes the target class but does not show the box

Answer (score 0):

because of `position: absolute;` and the same `bottom` value all divs shown as overlapped and you see the only last div.

if you remove `position: absolute;` from your style, it will toggle all divs, but it will toggle from up to down, different than yours.

or after toggle, increase bottoms

```js
$(".keyFeatures-span").click(function() { 
    $(".keyFeatures").toggleClass("selectedFeatures");
    $(".keyFeaturesBox").slideToggle("fast");
    
    $(".keyFeaturesBox").each(function(i,e){
        $(this).css("bottom" , i * 180); //180 is your box height in css
    });
});
```

```css
div.keyFeaturesBox, div.viewSavingsBox {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 180px; max-height: 180px;  
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid rgba(112, 112, 112, .34);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="vehicleDetails"><!-- Details start -->                
  <div class="keyFeatures">
    <span id="keyFeatures" class="keyFeatures-span">Key Features +</span>
  </div>
  <div class="viewSavings">
    <span id="viewSavings" class="viewSavings">View Savings +</span>
  </div>                
</div>

  <div class="keyFeaturesBox">
            <div class="keyFeaturesBox-header">
                <i id="keyFeaturesClose" class="far fa-times-circle"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="keyFeaturesBox-container">
                <div class="features">
                    <i class="fas fa-car"></i>
                    <span>Front Wheel Drive1</span>  
                </div>       
                <div class="features">
                    <i class="fas fa-car"></i>
                    <span>Front Wheel Drive</span>  
                </div>   
                <div class="features">
                    <i class="fas fa-car"></i>
                    <span>Front Wheel Drive</span>  
                </div>           
            </div>                
   </div>

  <div class="keyFeaturesBox">
            <div class="keyFeaturesBox-header">
                <i id="keyFeaturesClose" class="far fa-times-circle"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="keyFeaturesBox-container">
                <div class="features">
                    <i class="fas fa-car"></i>
                    <span>Front Wheel Drive2</span>  
                </div>       
                <div class="features">
                    <i class="fas fa-car"></i>
                    <span>Front Wheel Drive</span>  
                </div>   
                <div class="features">
                    <i class="fas fa-car"></i>
                    <span>Front Wheel Drive</span>  
                </div>           
            </div>                
   </div>

  <div class="keyFeaturesBox">
            <div class="keyFeaturesBox-header">
                <i id="keyFeaturesClose" class="far fa-times-circle"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="keyFeaturesBox-container">
                <div class="features">
                    <i class="fas fa-car"></i>
                    <span>Front Wheel Drive3</span>  
                </div>       
                <div class="features">
                    <i class="fas fa-car"></i>
                    <span>Front Wheel Drive</span>  
                </div>   
                <div class="features">
                    <i class="fas fa-car"></i>
                    <span>Front Wheel Drive</span>  
                </div>           
            </div>                
   </div>
```

Comment: I tested this solution but it didn't work, it really increases the bottom of the next box but if I click on another one besides the first it keeps the same with the bottom above, all are floating except the first.

Comment: what is another one besides the first? in your question, there is only one clickable item and it is "keyFeatures-span"

Comment: I'm creating a repeat loop that returns these cards, but each one is a different product, as it is a loop it is opening everyone's boxes on anyone I click